# certain trigonometric homeomorphisms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, polynomials, rational-functions, trigonometric-polynomials

Are there any simple characterizations of rational functions $f(x,y)$ with real coefficients such that $\theta\mapsto f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R\bmod 2\pi$ to $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ (the last set being the one-point compactification)?

(The fact that $\theta\mapsto\sec\theta+\tan\theta$ is such a homeomorphism despite the fact that each term separately is two-to-one onto its image and the first does not map onto the codomain, is what first made me think of this.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The magic words are $\tan(\theta/2).$ That substitution reduces your question to asking which rational functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphisms. Those are precisely the functions whose derivative does not change sign, so differentiating our function we get a rational function which does not change sign. This is true if and only if both the numerator and denominator do not change sign, so let's just say they stay positive (or non-negative if you want homeo instead of diffeo). A polynomial is nonnegative on the real line if and only if it is the sum of (two) squares.

So, there you have it.

**sum of two squares** to express a nonnegative polynomial as a sum of two squares, factor it over $\mathbb{C}.$ It will have either real roots of even multiplicity or conjugate complex roots. A quadratic polynomial with no real roots can be written as a sum of two squares ("completing the square"), an even power of a polynomial can be written as a sum of two squares (one of which is $0$), and now note that the product of sums of two squares is likewise a sum of two squares (think of norms)

**sigh** to complete the answer, note that if the rational function has a pole, it can only have *one simple* pole (otherwise, the map is not $1$-$1$ at infinity), furthermore, the limits at $\pm \infty$ have to be equal and finite. Suppose that pole is at $x=a.$ Precompose your function by a linear fractional $\phi$ which sends infinity to $a$ - $x \mapsto \frac{a x}{x+ a + 1}$ is my personal favorite. Now, you have a rational function which sends infinity to infinity, so you can apply what I had said before.

Comment: Derivative of $-1/x-1/(x-1)$ does not change sign but this is  not a homeomorphism.

Comment: How can one express, say, $(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2+(x-c)^2$ as a sum of *two* squares? (just curiosity)

Comment: @Qfwfq see the edit, though your case falls into the completing the square category ( notice that you have to take square roots to do this)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko You are right, of course -- my answer is not quit complete, but this is not hard to fix...

Comment: @IgorRivin : Your later edit certainly clarifies things.  If the only property of $\alpha\mapsto\tan\frac\alpha2$ that is relied on is that it is itself a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R\bmod2\pi$ to $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ then $\alpha\mapsto\sec\alpha+\tan\alpha$ also works (and no surprise there, since it is itself a tangent half-angle function, being equal to $\tan(\frac\pi4+\frac\alpha2)$), but also every function $\alpha\mapsto\text{some rational function of sine and cosine}$ that is itself such a homeomorphism will work just as well.

Comment: . . . . . so in other words, your answer amounts to showing that it's all reducible to just one such function.

Comment: @Qfwfq : I think Igor Rivin's later edit to his answer tacitly tells you how to construct an algorithm that would write $(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2+(x-c)^2$ as a sum of two squares of polynomials.  I was going to ask essentially the same question, but you beat me to it.

Comment: . . . . . and now I've looked at Alexandre Eremenko's example.  What he says is true.  His function is a two-to-one continuous mapping from the circle $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself, and it's locally one-to-one at every point and its derivative is everywhere positive.

Comment: More generally, any rational function of the form $R(z)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j/(z-p_j)$ ,where every $p_j$ is real and the $a_j$'s are real and all of the same sign, will be an $n$-to-$1$ mapping of $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ onto itself whose derivative does not change sign.

Comment: OK, I've decided to "accept" this incomplete answer, since I think I can work out the rest of it.

Comment: I'm not sure this question's been answered yet, but it's been reduced to a problem not involving trigonometric functions.  Neither of the two functions $x\mapsto (1+x^2)/(1-x^2)$ and $x\mapsto 2x/(1-x^2)$ is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself, but their sum is such a homeomorphism.  Just how addition and subtraction behave with respect to this class of functions could bear examination.

Comment: @MichaelHardy see the last edit.